# AWS Python boto3 lambda - getting the kinesis stream name

Tags: python-2.7, aws-lambda, boto3

I am a lambda in aws python boto3. I configured this lambda (a trigger) to read from a specific kinesis stream. It has to read the stream name from the event object. I don't know how to get the stream name. I don't want to hard code the Kinesis stream name in the code. I want to read it from event.

```
   import boto3
   import json
   from pprint import pprint

   s3 = boto3.client('s3')
   kinesis = boto3.client('kinesis')

  def lambda_handler(event, context):
       if event:

          for i in event["Records"]:
             print(i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see an example Kinesis record event at [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon Kinesis](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis.html).

Each record contains an `eventSourceARN`. To print the ARN of each event record:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for record in event["Records"]:
        print(record["eventSourceARN"])
```

You can infer the Kinesis stream name, if needed, from the ARN.